# How can magnetic fields be used to stop a rotating wheel?

Tags: magnetic-fields, rotational-dynamics

How can a rotating wheel stop using magnetic power? For example, consider a rotating iron wheel: can it be made to stop suddenly with using magnetic power? If so, how?

Comment: In a practical magnetic brake, you would make the "wheel" from some material such as copper or aluminum that is (a) _not_ ferromagnetic, and (b) a better conductor than iron. Being a better conductor makes it work more efficiently. Not being ferromagnetic avoids mechanical issues by eliminating any attractive force between the disk and the poles of the magnet.

Answer (score 1):

By placing the two poles of a strong magnet normal to the plane of rotation, eddy currents develop [if the moving object is a solid plate] and cause the motion to cease. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

By Lenz's law the direction of the current induced in a conductor (your iron wheel) by a changing magnetic field (the rotating iron wheel between magnet's poles feels a changing magnetic field relative to it) is such that the magnetic field created by the induced current **opposes** the initial changing magnetic field.

Or, more vaguely, the induced current opposes the change which induced it.

So the result is that the wheel will eventually stop (= no more change in a magnetic field).